# DECLARE @table TABLE ... no working variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use SQL Server 2016 (v13.0) and I try to get the timestamps of directory files.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[uz_imp_dir]
(
    datum smalldatetime NULL,
    filesuffix varchar(3) NULL,
    filename varchar(255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO uz_imp_dir (filename) VALUES ('C:\temp\test.txt')
INSERT INTO uz_imp_dir (filename) VALUES ('C:\temp\test2.pdf')
INSERT INTO uz_imp_dir (filename) VALUES ('C:\temp\test3.csv')

-- Start Main

DECLARE @cmd0 VARCHAR(500) = ''
DECLARE @datestamp smalldatetime
DECLARE @result TABLE (Line VARCHAR(255))
DECLARE @filename VARCHAR(400) = ''
DECLARE file_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT filename FROM uz_imp_dir
    OPEN file_cursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM file_cursor INTO @filename
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @cmd0 = 'dir /T:C ' + @filename + ' | find "test"' 
        INSERT INTO @result EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmd0
        SELECT @datestamp = CAST(SUBSTRING(Line, 1, 17) as smalldatetime) FROM @result
        UPDATE uz_imp_dir SET datum = @datestamp WHERE filename = @filename;
        FETCH NEXT FROM file_cursor INTO @filename
    END
    CLOSE file_cursor
    DEALLOCATE file_cursor
```

If I debug the code I don't see any values at the variable `@datestamp`.

If I manually try

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Line, 1, 17) FROM @result
```

I saw something like this *01.12.2020  11:49* and if I convert it to smalldatetime I get a good result like this *2020-12-01 11:49:00*

I try also to fill a simple `varchar` variable like

```
SELECT @stringresult = LEFT(Line, 17) FROM @result
```

but nothing works.

What can I use the `@result` to update my table uz_imp_dir or have somebody other ideas to get the timestamp from a directory file?

Comment: If `SELECT SUBSTRING(Line, 1, 17) FROM @result` returns you `01.12.2020 11:49`, then `SELECT @datestamp = CAST(SUBSTRING(Line, 1, 17) as smalldatetime) FROM @result` would save `01.12.2020 11:49` into `@datestamp`. If it does not, then either this is not the code you are running, or you are not debugging it properly, or there are null rows in `@result` and one of those null rows ends up being the one written into the variable (because your query means "save into `@datestamp` one random row from `@result`").

Comment: Do yourself a favour and write this in Powershell or batch cmd, or even C#. SQL is not the place for this, and the `xp_` procedures are undocumented, subject to removal at any time, and have security issues

Comment: For example in PS you can do `Get-ChildItem | where {$_.Name.Contains("test")} | select Name,CreationTime`, if you need that in a database then insert from PS using `Write-SqlTableData`

Comment: @Charlieface The [documentation to `xp_cmdshell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) does not seem to support any of your claims.

Comment: Thank You @GSerg

If you do
       `SET @cmd0 = 'dir /T:C ' + @filename + ' | find "test"' 
        INSERT INTO @result EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmd0
        SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(Line, 1, 17) as smalldatetime) FROM @result`

You get an good result as smalldatetime, but the next row dosn't fill the @datestamp varbiable
        `SELECT @datestamp = CAST(SUBSTRING(Line, 1, 17) as smalldatetime) FROM @result`
the debugger show no value in `@datestamp` and 
        `print @datestamp `
give no result 

Why?

Comment: What do you mean by good result? How many rows are there in the first place?

Comment: @GSerg You're right, looks like it is documented. But see this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/xp-cmdshell-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15 **"Newly developed code shouldn't use the xp_cmdshell stored procedure and generally it should be left disabled."**

Comment: @GSerg all true - but tsql obviously has no support for accessing the file system and activities like this don't really belong inside of the database engine. Security concerns and file system restrictions/permissions are very real issues - all of which are better addressed outside of the engine. Given the names involved, this appears to be the start of an **imp**ort ETL-type process - another reason to use a ETL tool and not tsql.

Comment: I find the problem
the dir command have two results
1. the datestamp 2. a NULL result  and that‘s what I get at the next SELECT and so no Result. Item is solved